# Altering my web site's Firefox New Tab page tile

Tags: html, firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I opened up Firefox this morning and was presented with the "New Tab" page. One of the tiles that appeared on this page was Mozilla's MDN site.

Unlike all the other tiles (which were merely screenshots of the web site), the MDN tile has a custom tile which advertised the MDN.

Looking at the HTML source for MDN I couldn't see any META or LINK tags that would suggest how they are achieving this?

I've Googled around but can't see any documentation about how I would go about customizing tiles for my own web sites so they display as pretty as MDN on this page..?

I was wondering if there was a standard mark-up for this so it would also work with Google Chrome's equivalent start page?

Looking on the Mozilla help page for Firefox users, you can see that tiles in their screenshots are not merely screenshots, but where can I see the web designer documentation for this..?

[image: See? The tiles are not screenshots in this photo like they are for most web sites]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not under the control of the site.

See [this bugzilla ticket](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1030832):

> > Can a website specify their own enhanced tiles via some meta tag?
>
> Right now no. There's been discussions around that, but there's
>   initially some worse privacy aspects where Firefox would need to
>   connect to a site to get that information potentially triggering
>   cookies similar to bug 1037673.
>
> How enhanced tiles are implemented is the content comes from
>   cookieless https requests to mozilla servers, so there's lower privacy
>   risks of some types of tracking.

Another ticket has been opened [requesting the feature](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1099402).

You would need to make a deal with Mozilla to get special treatment for your site on their servers.